# What's the common factored form of presenting Rao's score statistic?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, fisher-information

[Rao's score statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Score_test) is defined as

$$S(\theta_0) = \frac{U(\theta_0)^2}{I(\theta_0)}$$

where $U(\theta_0)$ is the score function and $I(\theta_0)$ is the Fisher information.

When one formulates $S$ for some particular distribution, then what's the general (e.g. factored) form of presenting $S$? Like what terms of $U$ should be factored and how should they be arranged?

Since e.g. if one plugs in the score function of a normal distribution, then the expression in the nominator can become quite complicated.

Comment: Or maybe I could calculate $\sqrt{S(\theta_0)}$ instead?